# Throttle body cleaner on rubber bad?

Tags: throttle-body, brake-cleaner

Was cleaning my throttle body and IACV using throttle body cleaner not brake cleaner and some dripped onto coolant rubber hoses and the IACV gasket.

Would this cause any damage? Make the rubber brittle?

Happened for about 20 seconds before I noticed and put rags to cover them up

Should I apply armor all to the hoses?

Comment: Rubber is generally an inert material ,I do not think its going to do any harm to rubber.Furthermore from what you have written 20 seconds is quite a small time frame for any reaction to take place

Comment: Haha ... some would say Armor All would do more damage to the rubber than the cleaner would ;-)

Comment: @DhKo So why do brake cleaner cans say not to get on plastic or rubber?

Comment: @user140123 it can dry the rubber out if used on rubber too often. It takes repeated action though. Not just once.